# How can I add a tooltip on features rendered by react-map-gl-draw's Editor?

Tags: reactjs, react-map-gl

I am attempting to render a tooltip every time one of my features is hovered in the `Editor` from `react-map-gl-draw`.

Ideally, I would like to be able to store the currently hovered feature index in a state. Like that I can render [`react-map-gl`'s `Popup`](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs/api-reference/popup) with appropriate coordinates. I believe there is no callback such as the `Editor`'s `onSelect` prop that would let me do that.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Map, {Popup} from 'react-map-gl';

function MapWithToolTip() {
  const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(true);

  return <Map
    initialViewState={{
      longitude: -100,
      latitude: 40,
      zoom: 3.5
    }}
    mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
  >
    {showPopup && (
      <Popup longitude={-100} latitude={40}
        anchor="bottom"
        onClose={() => setShowPopup(false)}>
        You are here
      </Popup>)}
  </Map>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my concern is how to retrieve longitude and latitude based on a hovered feature, rendered with `<Editor features={features} {...other props} />` from `react-map-gl-draw`